# Python function multiple arguments without calling function twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, algebra

I am trying to make a program that can do my algebra formulas. This is my code 
{

```
k = 3
k2 = 20

def algebra(number):
  print(5*number-10)

algebra(k)
```

}

I tried to do k2 and k at the same time like this

```
algebra(k,k2)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean "at the same time"? What's the result you want to get?

Comment: I want to run this function on both the variables(k and k2) but not call the funcition twice, which takes up 2 lines

Comment: `algebra(k)` and then `algebra(k2)` is the correct way to do that. Why do two things in a single line of code?

Comment: With print you could do `print(k,k2)` and it will print both variables

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to that or do you just like short code?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this  useful for you :

```
k = 3
k2 = 20

def algebra(*numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        print(5*number-10)

algebra(k,k2,k2)
```

output :
    5
    90
    90

Answer (score 0):

You could use `args` in your function, allowing you to call a function with multiple parameters. Your example would then become:

```
def algebra(*args):
  for arg in args:
    print(5*arg-10)

algebra(5, 10)
>> 15
>> 40
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is to call algebra on some variable number of k augments. There are a few ways to do this (map would likely be the most appropriate, but since you're just learning, I'll keep it simpler). One simple way is to have your function take in and return a list.

So you'd have somerh like

a = [k,k2]

And then in your algebra function, take a as an argument and iterate over its elements using a for loop like so:

For elem in a:

a[elem] = 5 * elem - 10

return a

And then print out the list that is returned in your main function